# firebase_app_distribution can not distribute to testers groups on CirclceCI

Tags: firebase, circleci, fastlane, circleci-2.0, firebase-app-distribution

On firebase console a testers group exists with name and alias, e.g. `test-group`. I'm distribution with:

```
firebase_app_distribution(
    app: ****,
    service_credentials_file: ***,
    groups: 'test-group',
    firebase_cli_token: ****
)
```

When run fastlane to distribute an app from localhost there is no problem with app distribution, but when run build on CircleCI it fails.

> [!] Could not enable access for testers. Check that the groups exist and the tester emails are formatted correctly
> Emails:
> Groups: ["test-group"]

Searching the error on Google didn't help. Also added `firebase_cli_token`, but no success. Also found a suggestion to add firebase tools to install CLI, the result is the same

```
  -
      run:
           name: "Install Firebase CLI"
           command: |
              curl -sL firebase.tools | bash
```

Does anybody face a similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and found it [here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/17339#issuecomment-700817745). It was a bug but it's fixed!

**Update the firebase plugin to `0.2.3`:**

`fastlane update_plugins`

or

change the version in your Gemfile.lock and do

`fastlane add_plugin firebase_app_distribution`